# What kind of breaches a bitcoin website could have?

Tags: vulnerability, databases

i want to develop a bitcoin website that allow users to deposit btc to their private address the website will generate , and i was told that i need an expert in information security in order to prevent any kind of hacking to the site.

And i was wondering what kind of vulnerabilities this kind of website could have? Except for the SQL injection i know about

Comment: The list of ways it could be vulnerable would be massive, a starting set would the OWASP top 10: https://www.owasp.org/images/7/72/OWASP_Top_10-2017_%28en%29.pdf.pdf

Comment: I don't want to be a buzzkill, but perhaps you should reconsider storing money for people if you have no idea where to start?

Comment: @TeunVink I was hoping to hire an expert to make sure everything i've done is fine , but i was told it must be done throughout the development

Comment: Trying to add security after the development is complete would be very unlikely to work, and would likely lead to a vulnerable system

Comment: This is a breach waiting to happen, you will be legally responsible if you lose people's details and / or money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above:

> The list of ways it could be vulnerable would be massive, a starting set would the OWASP top 10: Link

## OWASP top 10

- Injection
- Broken Authentication
- Sensitive Data Exposure
- XML External Entities (XXE)
- Broken Access Control
- Security Misconfiguration
- Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)
- Insecure Deserialization
- Using Components with Known
  Vulnerabilities
- Insufficient Logging & Monitoring

## Why cannot security be added to the system afterwards

To add security you would need to patch all of the issues in the code, which when added to the work to develop the system originally would be more than the amount of effort to develop the system securely.

Comment: If making sure the top 10 issues , are secure for sure , is the system still counted as vulnerable or it is safe to use?

Comment: Being secure about the top 10 does not make the site necessarily secure, it may still have loads of issues, but it does help to start finding exploits against a system.